# SQL Date Format Conversion YYYYMMDD

Tags: sql, sqldatatypes, date-formatting, dateadd, sql-date-functions

I have a table where a number of dates are stored as type Decimal(9,0) in the [DATE_READ] column. I need to use DATEADD on these entries so I am using the following code to convert them to varchar and then to dates:

```
    CASE WHEN A.[DATE_READ] <> 0 AND LEN(A.[DATE_READ]) = 6 
        THEN dateadd(day,1,CONVERT(date, '20' + CONVERT(varchar(8), A.[DATE_READ]), 112))
       WHEN LEN(A.[DATE_READ]) = 8
        THEN dateadd(day,1,CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), A.[DATE_READ]), 112))
```

My problem is that only the date is showing up as if I used 110 instead of 112 in the DATEADD function and only the first 8 characters appear so it looks like '2012-12-' instead of '20121205'. I don't mind what format the date is in but I need to get my code working so that I can see the days in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the final convert to 112. Since `DATEADD` returns a date, you need to format that date for output.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), 
 CASE 
  WHEN A.[DATE_READ] <> 0 AND LEN(A.[DATE_READ]) = 6 
  THEN dateadd(day,1,CONVERT(date, '20' + CONVERT(varchar(8), A.[DATE_READ]), 112))
 WHEN LEN(A.[DATE_READ]) = 8
  THEN dateadd(day,1,CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(10), A.[DATE_READ]), 112)) END,
112)
```

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed!